# Oracle - Selecting the n-1 record from a table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table of data and want to retrieve the penultimate record.

How is this done?

```
TABLE:        results
              -------
              30
              31
              35
```

I need to get 31.

I've been trying with rownum but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: +1 for correctly using the word _penultimate_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you want the second highest number and there are no ties

```
SELECT results
  FROM (SELECT results,
               rank() over (order by results desc) rnk
          FROM your_table_name)
 WHERE rnk = 2
```

Depending on how you want to handle ties, you may want either the `rank`, `dense_rank`, or `row_number` analytic function.  If there are two 35's for example, would you want 35 returned?  Or 31?  If there are two 31's, would you want a single row returned?  Or would you want both 31's returned.

Comment: There are no ties, but I need the penultimate row, which in this case is 2 but could be any number.

Comment: @RupertCobbe-Warburton - The penultimate row is always the second row assuming you are ordering correctly.  The concepts of "first row", "second row", "penultimate row", and "last row" only makes sense if you are imposing some sort of order.  If you simply reverse the order, the last row becomes the first row, the penultimate row becomes the second row, etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was trying to figure this out for hours!

Answer (score 0):

### This can use for n th rank ##

```
select Total_amount from (select Total_amount, rank() over (order by Total_amount desc) Rank from tbl_booking)tbl_booking where Rank=3
```

---